# What is a callback and how is it different from an update panel control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I just realized that I have been using controls that implement `ICallbackEventHandler` (callbacks) without understanding what they actually do and how they are different from an update panel.  Can someone please help me to understand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reasonable explanation found here.

http://www.componentart.com/community/blogs/milos/archive/2007/01/25/callback-vs-updatepanel.aspx

"UpdatePanels post the whole page, effectively performing a postback with each request. They do so asynchronously, so the original page stays put. The control then figures out which updateable areas of the page are affected by that postback (areas in UpdatePanels, essentially), and it redraws those areas, and updates ViewState. This mechanism preserves the old postback-based ASP.NET paradigm.

CallBack uses a different paradigm, simply letting you render some markup into a container, without posting the state of other controls (unless you want to). The rendering is not done via the usual ASP.NET mechanism, but through a server-side event handler, which determines exactly what gets sent back. Nothing else on the page can get modified, and ViewState is left untouched."

Comment: Almost makes one wonder why someone would ever use an update panel, doesn't it?

Comment: The article also addresses that. 

"For scenarios where the postback paradigm needs to be preserved (eg. there are inter-control dependencies, state of controls inside the panel needs to be maintained, usual asp.net rendering should be used, etc), UpdatePanels are recommended."

Comment: Understood properly except thing about VIEWSTATE, Can you explain it more specifically

Answer (score 2):

They're two different things.

A callback is an event triggered after the panel is updated. Often this is used to call some JavaScript on the client to open a panel or run some sort of UI effect on the item that was just updated or to set some form of client application state.