# Why And When Use ParentAbstractClass Obj =new Child Class() in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, callback

Actually I don't know whether it is a stupid question but because of my curiosity I am asking my 1 question. And I have 2 questions

1) I saw a video in YouTube about abstract class [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyU3bXyc_oU)

In that video, he is creating object of class using `Class Obj=new Class Obj();`
And my Question is Why he didn't use `AbstractClass Obj=new Child Class();`
Is there any difference between both? I mean between 
Parent Obj =new Child Class(); vs. AbstractClass obj=new ChildClass(); ?

2) My second Question is, I read a stack overflow question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5396459/what-is-a-callback-and-how-is-it-different-from-an-update-panel-control/5396684#comment34097495_5396684).
In the person who gave answer saying something about 
View State(`........ and ViewState is left untouched`). Actually I didn't understand about viewstate in his answer. I commented for explanation but no one gave me the answer. So can any one answer me what it means?

Some one please answer my question. And any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to ask only one question at a time. Post new question if they are not related.

Comment: As I understand, an abstract class is kind of general characteristics of a set of objects. In this case its the Employee. As you can see employees can be of different types and can have different behaviors, but still there are some common characterisitcs and beahviors for a set of employees eg: FirstName and LastName will behave same for both employee types. 
If there is a function which does some processing on `Employee` and expects a type `BaseEmployee`, that is when you instantiate a `FullTimeEmployee` into a `BaseEmployee` and pass it on to the method for processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't instantiate an abstract class, but you can create a concrete class with an abstract variable, for example:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream();   // Stream is an abstract class
```

The difference between this and

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
```

is that in the first example you can only invoke members present in the `Stream` class, because you invoke members on a variable, not an actual type. It's based on the fact that when `MemoryStream` inherits from `Stream` then every `MemoryStream` is also a `Stream` and sometimes you don't need full child class functionality (as in methods which expect a `Stream` in general, not a concrete implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say ParentClass an abstract class and ChildClass which inherits parent class

```
    public abstract class ParentClass 
{
 public int a;
public abstract void MethodA();
}
public class ChildClass :ParentClass
{
public override void MethodA()
{
//some implementation of child
}
public void MethodChildA()
{
//some implementation
}
}
```

Then
We could instantiate object  of child classusing ParentClass

```
ParentClass obj =new ChildClass();
```

obj hold member and method of childclass which it inherited from parent class
obj will not have the MethodChildA() implementation.obj.MethodChildA() is not possible since Type parentClass does not have declaration for MethodChildA()
**When**
Occassion where we want only parentclass member and method used then we will instantiate with type of object ParentClass.
Object include all methods of parentclass which may have implementation of childclass or
 ChildClass  will inherit concrete method of abstract 
**Why**
Consider a context where object must need only properties of parent class but not need of any method of child class

```
ChildClass obj=new ChildClass();
```

**When**
 If there is need of all method and members in the childclass